# How to extract nested JSON data with Python?

Tags: python, json

Now I'm trying to extract data by using Foursquare Venue API
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/categories

Foursquare Venue API's example is like this
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/categories

I've coded as below, and result is like this

```
56aa371be4b08b9a8d5734db    Amphitheater    Amphitheaters   Amphitheater
4fceea171983d5d06c3e9823    Aquarium    Aquariums   Aquarium
4bf58dd8d48988d1e1931735    Arcade  Arcades     Arcade
4bf58dd8d48988d1e2931735    Art Gallery     Art Galleries   Art Gallery
4bf58dd8d48988d1e4931735    Bowling Alley   Bowling Alleys  Bowling Alley
```

I don't know how to extract level 1 categories information such as 'Arts & Entertainment'

My code looks like this so far:

```
import json, requests


url ='https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/categories?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=SECRET_ID&v=20190910'

data = requests.get(url).json()


for each in data['response']['categories']:
    for i in each["categories"]:
        print  i["id"], '\t', i["name"],'\t', i["pluralName"],'\t', i["shortName"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the variables are named weirdly which prevents you from seeing things for what they are. Variable naming is super important :)

```
for category in data['response']['categories']:
    print  category["id"], '\t', category["name"],'\t', category["pluralName"],'\t', category["shortName"]
    for subcategory in category["categories"]:
        print  subcategory["id"], '\t', subcategory["name"],'\t', subcategory["pluralName"],'\t', subcategory["shortName"]
```